# display results in jsp by calling a servlet using jquery ajax?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, html

I want to call a servlet. servlet will fetch the data from database and keeps it in request. And the result  i need t display in `some.jsp` using jstl tags.

```
$('#ownForm #myButton').click(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "./controller",
            success: function(msg) {
                //Todo
            },
            error: function(ob,errStr) {
                //Todo

            }
        });

        });
```

In servlet i have below code:

```
//keep database returned list in request 
request.setAttribute("myresult", result);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/some.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Please help me how can i achieve it?

Comment: What is the problem? Don't you know how to reach the jsp? Don't you know how to use jstl-tags?

Comment: Problem is dont know how to reach the jsp..Thanks

Comment: What you are getting in the `success` of Ajax call. What data is it?

Comment: request.setAttribute("myresult", result);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/some.jsp").forward(request, response); this is the code i have in servlet. dont know how to invoke jsp on success of ajax call..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the jsp. Use FlexJson to serialize your result directly from the result object to json. Print the serialized result to the out stream in the response.

Something like this:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
JSONSerializer serializer = new JSONSerializer();
serializer.exclude("*.class"); //reduce clutter in your output as you see fit
serializer.serialize(objectToSerialize, response.getWriter());
```

Using jquery, parse this json and act on the result.

Comment: Gunslinger, Thankx for ur reply. But i get list of objects from database which needs to be displayed in jsp table.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem to return this list as json.